# Find sum in sublist

Tags: lisp

> Given a list `L=(M,A1,A2,...,An)`. Find sublist if they exist `L1=(Ai,Ai+1,...,Ai+k), i+k<=N, i>=1,`  for which  `M=Ai+Ai+1+...Ai+k`
>
> For example: `L=(1 3 -16 5 7 8 2 2), M=12`
>   Result: `L1=(1 3 -16)
>            L1=(5 7)
>            L1=(8 2 2)
>   for 5+7=12, 1+3-16=12, 8+2+2=12`

How to solve this in lisp?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this problem?

Comment: (setq l '(12 1 3 -16 5 7 8 2 2))

(defun sublist (myList)
(defun task((car myList)(cdr myList)
)
)
..................




(sublist l)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
(setq l '(6 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 -1))
(setq comb nil)
(setq rez nil)

(defun sublist (lst)
(secondfunction (car lst) (cdr lst)) 
)

(defun secondfunction (head other)
(run (cdr other) (cdr other) (list(car other)) (list(list(car other))))
(final comb head nil)
)

(defun final (lst el result)

(if (>(length lst) 0)
(progn
    (if(eq(loop for x in (car lst) sum x) el) (final (cdr lst) el (append result (cons (car lst) nil)))
    (if(>(length lst) 0)(final (cdr lst) el result )))
) 
(setq rez result)   
)

)

(final comb (car l) nil)

(defun run (lst1  lst2 temp r)

(if (not(eq(car lst1) nil))
    (if (not(eq(car lst2) nil))
        (run lst1 (cdr lst2) (append temp (list (car lst2))) (append r (list (append temp (list (car lst2))))))
        (run (cdr lst1) (cdr lst1) (list(car lst1)) (append r (list(list (car lst1)))))
    )
    (setq comb r)
)




)


(sublist l)
```

Answer (score 0):

### First try

Let's try to find one sublist first.

```
Sum  = 10
List = (2 4 3 3 1)
```

What if you tried to recurse? List is `(2 . (4 3 3 1))`, subtract 2.

```
Sum  = 8
List = (4 3 3 1)
```

Again:

```
Sum  = 4
List = (3 3 1)
```

Again:

```
Sum  = 1
List = (3 1)
```

Finally:

```
Sum  = -2
List = (1)
```

We failed, because the sum is negative.

### Discard the first element

We try again, but this time we skip the first element:

```
Sum  = 10
List = (4 3 3 1)
```

... etc.

```
Sum  = 0
List = (1)
```

Now we succeed, because the sum is zero, and we did not reach an empty list.

### Hints and questions

- we need to try all possible starting positions by skipping some N first elements;
- we can recurse to solve sub-problems, while decreasing the sum;
- there are different base cases, with the sum as well as the list;
- when the sum is zero, it means we iterated over the sublist we looked for;
- we need to somehow collect that sublist, where could we build it?
- how do we collect all the possible sublists?

### My take, obfuscated

```
(d.... s...... (s.. l...)
  (l.....
      ((s...... (s.. l... r.....)
         (c...
           ((m..... s..) n..)
           ((z.... s..) (l... (n....... r.....)))
           ((c.... l...) (d............-.... (h... . t...) l...
                           (s...... (- s.. h...) t... (l...* h... r.....))))
           (t n..))))
    (m..... (l..... (l...) (s...... s.. l... n..)) l...)))
```